# pyTelegramBotAPI Webhook not working on render.com

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm trying to run a telegram bot on render.com's web service with pyTelegramBotAPI
Previously, I ran the same code on heroku, and it worked well.

POST requests can be seen in the logs of render.com, but the bot does not respond.
How can I make this work?

my app.py:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
import telebot

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

URL = "https://a-telegram-bot.onrender.com/"
TOKEN = "<Telegram Bot Token>" 

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
app = Flask(__name__)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hello, ' + message.from_user.first_name)


# Webhook
@app.route('/' + TOKEN, methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
    bot.process_new_updates([update])
    return "!", 200


@app.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url=URL + TOKEN)
    return "!", 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
```

These are the logs from render.com with debug logging enabled
I sent '/start' command twice.

```
Nov 12 08:56:31 AM  ==> Starting service with 'gunicorn app:app'
Nov 12 08:56:36 AM  [2022-11-11 23:56:36 +0000] [53] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Nov 12 08:56:36 AM  [2022-11-11 23:56:36 +0000] [53] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:10000 (53)
Nov 12 08:56:36 AM  [2022-11-11 23:56:36 +0000] [53] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Nov 12 08:56:36 AM  [2022-11-11 23:56:36 +0000] [58] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 58
Nov 12 08:56:38 AM  2022-11-11 23:56:38,252 (apihelper.py:87 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5417454391:{TOKEN}/setWebhook params={'url': ''} files=None"
Nov 12 08:56:38 AM  2022-11-11 23:56:38,797 (apihelper.py:160 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was deleted"}''"
Nov 12 08:56:38 AM  2022-11-11 23:56:38,797 (apihelper.py:87 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5417454391:{TOKEN}/setWebhook params={'url': 'https://a-telegram-bot.onrender.com/5417454391:{TOKEN}'} files=None"
Nov 12 08:56:38 AM  2022-11-11 23:56:38,972 (apihelper.py:160 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}''"
Nov 12 08:56:38 AM  127.0.0.1 - - [11/Nov/2022:23:56:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "Go-http-client/2.0"
Nov 12 08:57:08 AM  2022-11-11 23:57:08,304 (apihelper.py:87 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5417454391:{TOKEN}/setWebhook params={'url': ''} files=None"
Nov 12 08:57:08 AM  2022-11-11 23:57:08,470 (apihelper.py:160 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was deleted"}''"
Nov 12 08:57:08 AM  2022-11-11 23:57:08,470 (apihelper.py:87 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5417454391:{TOKEN}/setWebhook params={'url': 'https://a-telegram-bot.onrender.com/5417454391:{TOKEN}'} files=None"
Nov 12 08:57:08 AM  2022-11-11 23:57:08,639 (apihelper.py:160 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}''"
Nov 12 08:57:08 AM  127.0.0.1 - - [11/Nov/2022:23:57:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
Nov 12 08:57:09 AM  2022-11-11 23:57:09,893 (apihelper.py:87 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5417454391:{TOKEN}/setWebhook params={'url': ''} files=None"
Nov 12 08:57:10 AM  2022-11-11 23:57:10,058 (apihelper.py:160 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was deleted"}''"
Nov 12 08:57:10 AM  2022-11-11 23:57:10,058 (apihelper.py:87 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5417454391:{TOKEN}/setWebhook params={'url': 'https://a-telegram-bot.onrender.com/5417454391:{TOKEN}'} files=None"
Nov 12 08:57:10 AM  2022-11-11 23:57:10,239 (apihelper.py:160 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}''"
Nov 12 08:57:10 AM  127.0.0.1 - - [11/Nov/2022:23:57:10 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://a-telegram-bot.onrender.com" "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
Nov 12 08:57:43 AM  2022-11-11 23:57:43,004 (__init__.py:668 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Received 1 new updates"
Nov 12 08:57:43 AM  127.0.0.1 - - [11/Nov/2022:23:57:43 +0000] "POST /5417454391:AAFaPxCiXtaGIBHNeK9JYYabcCM2lqYZryI HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
Nov 12 08:58:41 AM  2022-11-11 23:58:41,767 (__init__.py:668 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Received 1 new updates"
Nov 12 08:58:41 AM  127.0.0.1 - - [11/Nov/2022:23:58:41 +0000] "POST /5417454391:AAFaPxCiXtaGIBHNeK9JYYabcCM2lqYZryI HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
Nov 12 09:02:10 AM  2022-11-12 00:02:10,143 (apihelper.py:87 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5417454391:{TOKEN}/setWebhook params={'url': ''} files=None"
Nov 12 09:02:10 AM  2022-11-12 00:02:10,316 (apihelper.py:160 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was deleted"}''"
Nov 12 09:02:10 AM  2022-11-12 00:02:10,316 (apihelper.py:87 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "Request: method=get url=https://api.telegram.org/bot5417454391:{TOKEN}/setWebhook params={'url': 'https://a-telegram-bot.onrender.com/5417454391:{TOKEN}'} files=None"
Nov 12 09:02:10 AM  2022-11-12 00:02:10,485 (apihelper.py:160 MainThread) DEBUG - TeleBot: "The server returned: 'b'{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}''"
```

Answer (score 0):

For free accounts render does not allow threads. Therefore change

`bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)`

to

`bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN, threaded=False)`